# problems with /etc/sudoers

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo, chmod

I am running ubuntu 12.04 on i3 laptop. By mistake I changed the permissions and changed the user(from root) of /etc folder and I am getting a error when trying to use `sudo` like:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is made 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I have tried going to Recovery mode and root shell prompt and then I did following

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers 
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d
chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d 
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

but after every command it shows:

```
Read only file systems and it does nothing. Thanks in advance for your help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remount the filesystem as read/write

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and run those chown/chmod again.